# Docker gives no error but no output on console

Tags: docker, flask

Hi I have a Flask app tha I'm running on docker.
On running the app, I get no error but no output too. The cursor keeps blinking. Is something happening in background? How can I check the logs?

**EDIT:**

Hi 
I have a Flask-Docker application.
If I use the following, the app runs fine on docker:

```
 app.run(debug=True, port=5000, host='127.0.0.1')
```

However, if I use the following, Docker gets stuck:

```
app_server = gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer('0.0.0.0:5000', app)
app_server.serve_forever()
```

If I run without Docker, both run fine.

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY . /root/
WORKDIR /root/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

Commands to build and run:

```
docker image build -t prj .

docker container run --publish 5000:5000 --name clf clf
```

**EDIT 2**
I changed the dockerfile to this:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN mkdir /code  
ENV PYTHONPATH /code
WORKDIR /code  
ADD . /code/  
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD ["run.sh"]
```

I also added a run.sh file whose contents are:

```
flask run --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5000
```

and am using WSGI server instead of app.run() like I want to.

The console now shows that the app is running on 127.0.0.1:5000 as expected.
However, this link is still unreachable from browser.

Comment: Could you post your dockerfile as well as how you built and ran your container?

Comment: No one is God over here. Share the Dockerfile and relevant code.

Comment: Provided the relevant edits. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The flask runs by default on port 5000.

Try running as said below.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 YOUR-FLASK-APPLICATION.
```

Copied the above command from below link, in case the link goes off in future.

Go to "Further Information" section of

https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-flask-application